# Postgresql join tables to several columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I have a list of students' name called table Names and I want to find their categories from another table called Categories as below:

```
Class_A    Class_B    Class_C  Class_D  Category
Sam                   Adam              High
            Sarah                       Medium
James                                   High
Emma        Simon               Nick    Low
```

My solution is to do a left join but students name from first table should be matching with one of four columns so I am not sure how to write queries. At the moment my query is just matching to Class_A while I need to check all categories and if the student's name exist, return category.
(Note: some rows have more than one student's name)

```
SELECT Names.name, Categories.Category 
FROM Names
   LEFT JOIN Categories ON Names.name = Categories.Class_A;
```

Table Names looks like this:

```
Name
----
Emma
Nick
James
Adam
Jack
Sarah
```

And I am expecting an output as below:

```
Name     Category
----     ----
Emma     Low
Nick     Low
James    High
Adam     High
Jack     -
Sarah    Medium
```

Comment: Please show us the expected output, unless you've already shown that above, in which case you should show us the input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to unpivot the first table.  This looks like:

```
select n.name, c.category
from name n left join
     (categories c cross join lateral
      (values (c.class_a), (c.class_b), (c.class_c), (c.class_d)
      ) v(name)
     )
     on n.name = v.name
where v.name is not null;
```

Although you can also solve this using `in` (or `or`) in the `on` clause, that may produce a much less efficient execution plan.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, I will try it and then comment later

Answer (score 1):

Try this using OR in on clause:

```
SELECT Names.name, coalesce(Categories.Category,'-') as category 
FROM Names
   LEFT JOIN Categories ON Names.name = Categories.Class_A or Names.name = Categories.Class_B or Names.name = Categories.Class_C or Names.name = Categories.Class_D
```